# InvalidAuthenticationToken error using msal and graph api from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, msal-react

I am using the example [msal-react](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-react) to authenticate and consume sharepoint services using their graph api, create an application on AAD with delegated permissions.

I am assigning the scopes **"https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/.default"** and I get the following error code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken" message: "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience." check the token I get on the JWT.io page [image].
Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 0):

You are using the graph API to perform CRUD operations for SharePoint sites, so you should get an access token for the graph API instead of the SharePoint REST API.

So please change your `scope` to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: I am using Graph API and endoint that I use is the following:

"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{IdSite}}/lists/List Contact/items?$Select=Id&$expand=fields"
When I log in with a sharepoint administrator user and I get the access token I can consume the sharepoint graph api services without problem, this error happens when I log in with a user who does not have permissions in the sharepoint, but I am interested in being able to consume the services without it being able to access the sharepoint.

Comment: You must grant the user the appropriate graph API permissions to call this API endpoint.

Comment: I am checking to see if this issue is resolved or not. If you have any concerns, please feel free to reply.

Comment: These permissions must be given in the online sharepoint, in the "site permissions" section, is this correct?

Comment: You need to give these API permissions in your Azure AD application like [this](https://i.imgur.com/xJve1r3.png).

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one SPA application and added SharePoint **API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/.default 
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
code_verifier:S256
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the token, it has `SharePoint` as **audience** and **`scp`** claim as below:

[image]

I got the **same error** as you when I used above token to call SharePoint from below graph API call:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/lists
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, assign **Microsoft Graph API** permissions for SharePoint like below:

[image]

Now, generate the **access token** again by changing the scope to **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** as suggested by *@Carl Zhao* like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
code_verifier:S256
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token, I got **Microsoft Graph** as audience and **`scp`** claims are as below:

[image]

When I used above token to call **SharePoint site lists** from below graph API call, I got the **results** successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/lists
```

**Response:**

[image]

Note that, your token **audience** should be https://graph.microsoft.com while making graph calls and **`scp`** claim should contain **Microsoft graph** permissions.

Comment: thanks for your reply:
I am currently getting "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com" as audience when decoding the token, however I did the steps you mentioned again and still got the same error.
What happens, I can access the graph api services when I authenticate with a user who has permissions to see the sharepoint, what I want is to be able to consume the services without first giving the user permissions to access the sharepoint

Comment: Without giving the permissions, you cannot access SharePoint. Make sure to **grant** required permissions before accessing SharePoint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, I am going to resort to assigning minimum privileges in sharepoint